# Object saving array in string type in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I got a string from field, and split it to array, but when i saving array into object, its saving like string, not like array

```
const inputChangeHandler = (field) => {
if (Array.isArray(translation[field])) {
                    setChanges({...changes, [field]: window.event.target.value.split(',')});
                }
                setChanges({...changes, [field]: window.event.target.value});
            }
```

Expected:

```
{
 [field] : [Value1, Value2, Value3]
}
```

Actual:

```
{
    [field]: "Value1,Value2,Value3"
}
```

Comment: did you mean `else { ... }`?

Comment: OMG, really forget `else`, xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `setChanges` set the string to your `field`. So you need to remove second `setChanges`

```
setChanges({...changes, [field]: window.event.target.value});
```

Comment: really forget about `else`, thx